# When un-used Instant Apps are deleted?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

We would like to understand for Instant Apps lifetime.

App Clips for iOS's instant apps are "30 days".
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212238

> App clips are automatically removed from your device after 30 days of non-use.

But Instant Apps lifetime are not found in Android developers pages.

Please tell us Instant Apps lifetime.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/272586517

> If an instant app isn't used on a device for 7 days, it's removed to free up the user's space. Note that the 7-day window is an implementation detail that is subject to change.